# C# Is it possible to convert EventArgs to FormClosingEventArgs when calling method in a method?

Tags: c#, formclosing

I've made a form closing event when X is pressed, but I also want the 'Exit' button to call this same method yet it draws me error every time I change stuff.

--- This code below is the form closing event ---

```
// if user pressed 'Exit' button or red cross
private void TempConverterForm1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e) {
    DialogResult exitdialog = MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to quit?", "Quit?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel);

    if (exitdialog == DialogResult.Yes) {
        e.Cancel = false;
    }

    else {
        e.Cancel = true;
    }
}
```

--- This code below is the code I'm trying to solve ---

```
// if the 'exit' button is pressed
private void btn_Exit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
    TempConverterForm1_FormClosing(sender, (FormClosingEventArgs) e);
}
```

I've tried without `FormClosingEventArgs` first but on itself it says that `EventArgs` can't be converted to closing event. I put `FormClosingEventArgs` but now it tries to convert from `MouseEventArgs` to `FormClosingEventArgs` even though I relate to button click and not mouse click.
I tried to do research but the problem repeats and builds up with different error messages and I got lost and decided I need help with this.

Comment: The general solution for such cases is to [extract method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/reference/extract-method): make common method and call it from both event handlers. In your specific case just call `Close()` in button click (as per [@RichN answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63073611/1997232)).

Comment: Creating your own FormClosingEventArgs object is entirely appropriate, there is no "law" that demands that only winforms can do it.  Spamming the user with a message box whose response is Yes, 999 out of a thousand times, isn't.

Comment: Thank you. I did know that but in future I might need to call methods including this in advanced programs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do this.Close() in btn_Exit_Click.  This will fire Form_Closing correctly with the right arguments, and your cancel will still work.

```
private void btn_Exit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
       this.Close();
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I did know that but in future I might need to call methods including this in advanced programs.